# Getting crashed while dequeuing collection view header using xib in swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Here I am using custom collection view flow layout and cell has been loaded successfully using xib while loading header using xib got crashed can any one help me what's wrong in it ?

Here is my view did load code

```
 let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "searchHistoryCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil)
        self.searchCollectionView.register(cellNib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "hotSearchCell")
        let headerNib = UINib(nibName: "searchSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView", bundle: nil)
        self.searchCollectionView.register(headerNib, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "searchHeader")
```

here is my collection view header code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50) //add your height here
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let header = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "searchHeader", for: indexPath) as! searchSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView
            header.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.9578801208, green: 0.9578801208, blue: 0.9578801208, alpha: 1)
            header.hotSearchLabel.text = " Hot Search"
            header.deleteButton.isHidden = true
            return header
        }
        else {
            let header = searchCollectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "searchHeader", for: indexPath) as! searchSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView
            header.backgroundColor =  #colorLiteral(red: 0.9578801208, green: 0.9578801208, blue: 0.9578801208, alpha: 1)
            header.hotSearchLabel.text = " Search History"
            header.deleteButton.isHidden = false
            header.deleteButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearHistoryData), for: .touchUpInside)
            return header
        }
    }
```

here is my xib image

[image]

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle
>   /Users/ewall-mac-2/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/1DF7324A-FFEA-47B7-B6C3-C03A09B80B7B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B1132E40-14E6-421C-BBCE-3BE142C82CFB/My.app (loaded)' with name 'searchSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView''
>   *** First throw call stack:

Comment: What is the name of the xib file that this cell is in?

Comment: this is the cell name searchSectionHeaderCollectionReusableView @GeorgeGreen

Comment: here is my image https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASNxO.png @GeorgeGreen